# How to append a column from back into a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset in which **redshift** column is in the middle of the first and last column, So I want to swap the redshift column with the last column
[image: As in Given DataFrame redshift is in middle I want redshift column as the last column of DataFrame]

I tried this code

```
x=dataset.drop('redshift',axis=1)
y=dataset['redshift']
x['redshift']=y
dataset=x
```

now after executing this code dataset is having redshift as the last column but when Saving this Dataframe into CSV file and Loading again that csv file I am not getting that redshift as last column. Getting same dataframe as in above image.

Comment: I read your post 7 times and I don't understand where this column was and where it should be at the end.

Comment: so you move redshift to the end, save it as a csv and then are confused that redshift is the last column in that csv?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think my answer is right. The more I read your question, the less I understand it :)

Comment: @Wilian Now read the question updated

Comment: @EmiOB yes not confused but after into csv when I loaded that csv in dataframe I found redshift was not last column

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, try:

```
y = dataset['redshift']              # <- swap this line
x = dataset.drop('redshift',axis=1)  # <- and this line
x['redshift'] = y
dataset['redshift'] = x              # <- set column name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to `pop` of a column from a dataframe.

```
y = dataset.pop('redshift')
X = dataset
```

Now why is a pd.Series of 'redshift' and X is the original dataset without 'redshift'.

To add 'redshift' back to dataset at the end:

```
dataset['redshift'] = y
```

Comment: I want to pop redshift and then push at the last of the dataset means I want redshift as the last column of dataset.

Comment: @maneeshsagar See updated.